Change image in a BoxLayout when an action occurs in another Box Layout
I have a sort of note-taking app I'm putting together.  It has a horizontal BoxLayout which contains an image and another BoxLayout (which happens to be vertical).  This embedded BoxLayout contains a TabbedPanel.
I want to change the image in the main BoxLayout whenever the user selects a different tab in the embedded BoxLayout.
I'm not sure what to do in the on_release() method of each TabbedPanelItem in order to get the different images to display.
Currently I have the layout working the way I want up to the point of displaying the image for the first (default) tab.
Here is my code:

main.py
layouttest.kv

In the KV code, I have set the source of the Image to app.leftImage.  In the 3 on_release() handlers, I set app.leftImage to the correct image.  But that doesn't change what is displayed.
There is probably something simple that I am not understanding, but I am new to Kivy programming, so please answer with sufficient detail for a newbie to grasp.

I had to add an id to both the BoxLayout and the Image.  I also added a property to the BoxLayout to hold the image widget id.  Then, in the on_release handler for each TabbedPanelItem, I had to pass the property to the handler.  In each handler, I set the image source to the correct image.
In Kivy code:
    BoxLayout:
        id: mainBox
        leftImage: image
        ...

        Image:
            id: image
        ...

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    id: tab_ref
                    text: 'Tab1R'
                    on_release: app.showTab1R(r_list, mainBox.leftImage)

In Python code:
    def showTab1R(self, ref_list, image):
        image.source = self.Tab1RImage


In order for kivy to automatically update the Image, The source must refer to a Property. Try changing:
leftImage = Tab1RImage

to:
leftImage = StringProperty(Tab1RImage)


that doesn't work.  I get an error "Unresolved reference 'Tab1RImage' "...

To get around the error, I had to use self.Tab1RImage.  But the behavior now is the same as in the beginning.
